# Time Series, linear regression and ARMA

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, linear-model, armax

I have time dependent data, I used linear regression for trend and seasonality, for residuals I used an ARMA (p, q). Then I improved my regression by adding the adjusted values of the two models and it worked very well.

My question is, is there any way to improve my model betas and not just the fit?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fit the models simultaneously to gain efficience for estimators of the betas. E.g. in R, use functions `arima` or `auto.arima` with regressors specified via the `xreg` argument.

Comment: thanks to you I found the sarimax models. thanks you!